# Order for signature in email or document

Tags: sentence-construction

I always get confused when I write my signature on word/powerpoint documents or in email.

If I want my signature to include:

- my name, section name, department name, factory name, and company name
- section name, department name, factory name

How can I put these in order? In my country, my name comes last but I think it does not apply to english.

Comment: The order you have looks fine to me (from Australia). I would call the information a *signature block*, though. The word *signature*, for many people, refers to a hand-written name, though these days it may refer to a digital method of authenticating the person who has authorised a document.

Comment: Thank you! I was struggling searching for examples since I didn't know the word "signature block".  So when I put these information on the cover page of my power point, can I just put commas in between?

Answer (score 1):

There is no prescribed order for this sort of information in English. IN GENERAL, we give it from most specific to most general. So for example, your name, your department, then your company. An individual person is most specific, a department presumably includes many people, and the company includes many departments. But if you gave it in some other order, it's unlikely anyone would question it.

Ditto Peter that in English we call this a "signature block" and not a "signature". Signature is just your name, hand written.

Comment: Thank you! I did't know there aren't any specific rules to it. Can I just put commas in between? e.g. Johnny Depp, Law department, NY plant, Toyota

Comment: There are no specific rules to it.  That said, it is not meant to be an address.  You include your name, and you might include your *role*.

Comment: In my UK (British) government finance job, the part of an email under my name (department and phone number) is called just the 'signature' or 'email signature' and there is no doubt about what is meant when we use the term, because of the context.

Comment: If it might be ambiguous, you could certainly say, "Department: Accounting", or "Accounting department". But if it's obvious there's not much need. Like if you say "Toyota", I think most people would understand that's the name of a company. If you work for the "Toyota department" of some other company, you might specify that that's a department name. If this information is for people in your own company, they're more likely to know department and factory names than the general public.

Comment: @jamesk Sure, include the information that's relevant to your audience. Like in my posts here, I've never mentioned the company I work for because it's nothing to do with speaking English so it's not relevant. Maybe if I worked for the "English Language Institute" I would mention it. If you're giving a company presentation and the particular factory you work at is relevant, yes, mention it. If not, if no one cares, then don't waste time with it.

Comment: If practical, put each "thing" on a separate line. If that's not practical -- not enough room, in the middle of a paragraph, whatever -- separating them with commas is acceptable.